# Do we need to add a comma before "as"

Tags: punctuation, commas

Do we need to add a comma before "**as**" in the following sentence?

> I am writing to inform you that I would not able to attend the course
>   from 19 February **as** my new shift timings match the course timings.

Comment: Strictly speaking you *should* include the comma, but what marks the text out as "sub-standard" to me isn't that "missing" comma anyway. It's the use of [hypothetical?] ***would*** rather than ***will***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you.Duly noted. is there a better word for "match" in this scenario...I think match does not fit in.

Comment: Without the comma, the "as" would be read as "in the role of," e.g., "...attend the course as an auditor." Context rescues the meaning, but context should be a last resort where there is no benefit of brevity to be achieved by relying on it. I think "work schedule conflicts with the course hours" would be more idiomatic than what you have written.  And I second FumbleFingers on "will" vs. "would," unless a real possibility exists that the course hours will be changed. In that case, you are telling the prof. why those hours should be changed, rather than why you will not be attending.

Comment: @remarkl, so you suggest to go for comma before as?

Comment: Personally, I think ***...are a good fit with*** or ***...fit in [well] with...*** would be better than ***match*** here. But that's a really fine detail of *style* - there's nothing particularly *wrong* with your phrasing there.

Comment: Ooops! just realized that in context, the whole point is that *the new shift timings **clash with** the course timings* ("matching" would only normally be used where there's some kind of *desirable* relationship - which apparently *isn't* the case here, since it's preventing you from attending.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can it be said that "would" is incorrect if we are unaware of the full context? Let's suppose "I am writing to inform you that (whilst I could attend if it began in January) I would not be able to attend the course from 19 February..."

Comment: @WS2: I'd say that something ***would*** normally be the case ***if*** something else were also true, not ***as / because of*** something else.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Equally you "would not" if something else of inconvenience were true. Let's say this chap has been told that they can't decide whether to run the course from 19 Jan or 19 Feb, and does he have a preference? He replies saying "I could attend in January, but "I would not be able to attend from 19 Feb as my shift patterns are changing".

Comment: Yes, I go for the comma.

Comment: @WS2: That one's a bit more "ambiguous" - ***would*** can seem natural because it matches preceding ***could***, implying the whole situation is only "tentative / hypothetical". But following ***as = because*** still argues for ***will not*** (or more likely ***won't***). My choice there would probably be affected by whether we're talking about *the one and only date* on which I might go somewhere, or a series of events, *some of which* I might not attend.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess what I'm saying is that we don't know what sentence(s) have preceded this. But there are circumstances where "would" would seem perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @remarkl I am writing to inform you that I "will" not "be" able to attend the course from 19 February, as my new "shift hours coincide (or overlap)" with the course hours.

Comment: BTW, "I am writing to inform you that..." is always wasted verbiage.  Not only does it waste everyone's time, it has an opportunity cost, squandering the chance to start with a real mood-setter, such as "sadly, "unfortunately," or the more melodramatic "To my great disappointment,".

Answer (score -1):

Despite all these comments, no-one has attempted an answer. Since I disagree with most of the comments, I thought I should give this answer. Please note I am a native BrE speaker.

If you wish to be very polite then you might well choose "would" rather than "will". In the context of a student addressing a professor, politeness might be appropriate. The element of doubt implied by "would'" permits a polite withdrawal: the professor might change the timings; you might decide that you could change your other commitments. "Will" could be read as an ultimatum.

There are a few occasions in which the omission of a comma changes the meaning of a sentence. This is not one of them. The modern taste is for minimal commas.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I am giving IELTS in a few days and so I am planning to understand the possibilities of the scenario. From IELTS perspective or strictly speaking, do we have to give a comma in my sentence?

Comment: _Would_ does not add any politeness in this context – it just confuses. _Will_ here is a plain future marker, and there is no reason to shift this into the past. Doing so yields a very jarring and absolutely _not_ formal sentence.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It is not a shift into the past but into the conditional ('If the times stay as proposed, I would not...'). Jarring or not, it's what many people would say.

Comment: @JeremyC The conditional _is_ temporally future past. Personally I have never heard anyone use a conditional in this context; present, present continuous, future and future continuous are all perfectly good options, but not conditionals.

Comment: 'I am writing to inform you that I will not able to attend the course from 19 February as my new boss has insisted we get to grips with our paperwork' arguably has its sense changed by the inclusion of a comma (though I'd rephrase).